# Visual studio and AWS Glue job debugging

Tags: visual-studio, pyspark, aws-glue

Currently we write the Glue jobs using Visual studio and test the same from command line using [Glue ETL library](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-programming-etl-libraries.html). Unfortunately, our setup is not good for debugging.

Is there any way to configure the VS so that we can do local debugging (setting breakpoint, watch etc)?

If Visual studio doesn't support it, is there any other IDE which supports this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is a pretty [detailed guide](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-glue-developer-guide/blob/master/doc_source/dev-endpoint-tutorial-pycharm.md) on how you can setup nice local development environment with [PyCharm Professional](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/). It covers:

- Connecting PyCharm Professional to a Development Endpoint
- Deploying the Script to Your Development Endpoint
- Starting the Debug Server on `localhost` and a Local Port
- Initiating Port Forwarding
- Running Your Script on the Development Endpoint

**NOTE:** PyCharm professional requires subscription, although it gives you a trial period of 1 month.